# Algorithm to optimally group list of values

Tags: algorithm

I have several numbers. I need to group them in several groups, so that sums of all numbers in one group are between predefined min and max. The point is to left as few numbers ungrouped as possible.

```
Input:
    min, max: range for sum of numbers
    N1, N2, N3 ... Ni: numbers to group
Output:
    [N1,N3,N5],[Ni,Nj,Nk,Nm...]...: groups where sum of numbers is between min and max
    Na,Nb,Nc...: numbers, left ingrouped.
```

Comment: This is not a question; it's a work description. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: just to be clear: as few numbers ungrouped, or the smallest cumulative value of the ungrouped numbers? Would you rather be left with a single 3? or two 1's?

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be viewed as bin packing into bins of size `max`, with a funny objective: minimize the number of items not packed into bins holding at least `min`. One idea from the bin-packing literature is that the "small" items (in this case, items that are small relative to `max - min`) are easy to pack but are accountable for most of the combinatorial explosion of possibilities. Thus some approximation algorithms for bin packing do something clever for big items and then fill in with the small. Another way to reduce the number of possibilities is to round the numbers to belong to a smaller set. It's somewhat obvious how to do that for bin packing (round up), but it's not clear what to do for this problem.

---

Okay, I'll give an example of how these ideas could be instantiated. Suppose that max = 1 and min = 1/2. Let's try to find a solution that's competitive with the optimum for when max = 2 and min = 1/2. (That may sound terrible, but this sort of approximation guarantee where OPT is held to higher standards is sometimes used in the literature.)

First round every item's size up to a power of 2. Very large items, of size 4 or greater, can't be packed. Large items, of size 2 or 1 or 1/2, are given their own bins. Small items, of size 1/4 or less, are dealt with as follows. Whenever two items of size 1/4 or less have the same size, combine them into one super-item. Pack all of the new items of size 1/2 into their own bins. The remainder has total size less than 1/2. If there is space in another bin, put them there. Otherwise, give them their own bin.

The quality of the resulting solution for max = 2 is at least as good as the quality of OPT for max = 1. Take the optimal solution for max = 1 and round the item sizes. The set of bad bins remains the same, because no item is smaller, and each bin stores less than 2 because each item is less than twice as large as it used to be. Now it suffices to show that the packing algorithm I gave for powers of 2 is optimal. I'll leave that as an exercise.

**I don't expect this instantly to generalize into a full algorithm.** I have to get back to work, but the approach I would take would be to force OPT to deal with max = 1 while ALG gets to use max = 1 + epsilon, substitute powers of (1 + epsilon) for powers of two in the rounding step, and then figure out how to pack the small items, probably using a dynamic program since greed likely won't work.

Comment: @Ricky Bobby I hope you find my edit useful. Reading over my answer, I guess the main idea is to measure approximate optimality by comparing the algorithm against a more constrained optimum. I hope this is OK for F0RR's use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about efficiency, simply generate each possible grouping and choose the one that is correct and optimal in the sense you describe. Clearly, this works for any finite list of numbers (and is, by definition, optimal).

If efficiency is desired, the problem seems to become somewhat more difficult. :D I'll keep thinking.

EDIT: Come to think of it, this problem seems at least as hard as "subset sum" and, as such, I don't think there is a solution significantly better than the one I give (i.e., no known polynomial-time algorithm can solve it, if it is NP-Hard.